# How to get the child factories from a parent factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I am using RSpec and FactoryGirl to test my Ruby-on-Rails-3 application.  I am using a hierarchy of factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :local_airport do

    ... attributes generic to a local airport

    factory :heathrow do
      name    "London Heathrow"
      iata    "LHR"
    end

    factory :stansted do
      name "Stansted"
      iata "STN"
    end

    ... more local airports
  end
end
```

In my RSpec I sometimes want to be able to create all the child factories by specifying the parent factory.  Ideally, something like:

```
describe Flight do
  before( :each ) do
    # Create the standard airports
    FactoryGirl.find( :local_airport ).create_child_factories
  end
end
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a few hours of delving in the FactoryGirl code I have found a solution.  Interestingly FactoryGirl only stores a reference to the parent in the factory, and not from parents to children.

In spec/factories/factory_helper.rb:

```
module FactoryGirl
  def self.create_child_factories( parent_factory )
    FactoryGirl.factories.each do |f|
      parent = f.send( :parent )
      if !parent.is_a?(FactoryGirl::NullFactory) && parent.name == parent_factory
        child_factory = FactoryGirl.create( f.name )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my RSpec I can now write:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Flight do
  before( :each ) do
    # Create the standard airports
    FactoryGirl.create_child_factories( :local_airport )
  end

  ...
```

One gotcha I found is that it is best to have a factory hierarchy that is simple (i.e. two levels).  I started with a three layer hierarchy and found I was generating 'abstract' factories that only existed as part of the hierarchy.  I have simplified the hierarchy to two levels using traits.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really tell a factory to build all it's child factories, as being a child factory just means that it inherits the attributes from the parent. But what you could do is add a trait, for example `:with_child_factories`. Then your factory would look like the following:

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :local_airport do

        ... attributes generic to a local airport

        factory :heathrow do
          name    "London Heathrow"
          iata    "LHR"
        end

        factory :stansted do
          name "Stansted"
          iata "STN"
        end

        ... more local airports

        trait :with_child_factories do
          after(:create) do
            FactoryGirl.create(:heathrow)
            FactoryGirl.create(:stansted)
            ...
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Then you could call it in your test with

```
        FactoryGirl.create(:local_airport, :with_child_factories)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  My only concern is that I will need to keep the list of factories in the trait properly correlated to the factories.  I was hoping for something that the list of factories is automatically generated.